# What are the odds of one card being drawn last.

Tags: probability

What are the odds of one card being drawn last when each card is discarded before the next one is drawn, consequently the deck would go from 52 to 51, etc

Answer (score 2):

We assume the deck is well-shuffled. Then all permutations of the cards are **equally likely**. So the probability is $1/52$ if the deck has the standard $52$ cards.

For intuition, it is clear that the probability that the $\spadesuit$ Ace is last is the same as the probability that the $\clubsuit$ $7$ is last.

**Remark:** In the language of *odds*, the answer is $1\colon 51$ for, or $51\colon 1$ against.   Odds are less convenient than probabilities for most calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The chances of a card being the first are 1/52. so if you take the deck and flip it the chance of getting the last card is also 1/52.

Answer (score 0):

If you flip the deck upside-down, this is the same thing as asking the probability of a card being drawn first.

More generally, if you cut the deck to the nth position before drawing a card, you can readily see that the probability of any given card being in any particular position will be $1/52$.